# React and bootstrap: component not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to render simple bootstrap components using react.

This is index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/react/react.js"></script>
  <script src="js/react/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="js/browser.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 
 <body>
    <div class="container" id="headContainer">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <img src="Panter.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
               <h1 style="color:Pink">To do, to do, to doooo</h1>
          </div>
       </div> 
    <div id="list">
       
    </div>
    </div> 
 <script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js" ></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is app.js:

```js
var ListOfActionsRendering=React.createClass({
   render: function() {
    return (       
     <div class="accordion" id="listOfActions">
     <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#listOfActions" href="#defaultList">
                 <h4 id="nameOfGroup"> Основной список </h4>
              </a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group">
                 <button class="btn" onclick="onEditListOfActionClick()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                 <button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
              </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     
      <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="defaultList">
             <div class="accordion-inner">
                 <a href="#defaultList">
                  <h5>  </h5>
                 </a> 
          </div>
         </div>
  </div>
         
        );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render (
   <ListOfActionsRendering />,
   document.getElementById("list")
);
```

I dont have any errors in chrome console, but components are not shown.

In snipper I have an Error:

message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <,
  filename: http://stacksnippets.net/js,
  lineno: 16,
  colno: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSX, just change `class=""` to `className=""`:

```
var ListOfActionsRendering=React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       return (         
        <div className="accordion" id="listOfActions">
           <div className="accordion-group">
              <div className="row">
                 <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <a className="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#listOfActions" href="#defaultList">
                       <h4 id="nameOfGroup"> Основной список </h4>
                    </a>
                 </div>

                 <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <div className="btn-group">
                       <button className="btn" onclick="onEditListOfActionClick()"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                       <button className="btn"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>

            <div className="accordion-body collapse in" id="defaultList">
                <div className="accordion-inner">
                    <a href="#defaultList">
                        <h5>  </h5>
                    </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        );
   }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you think my answer is useful, please consider an up-vote, too, thanks! If you have further issues with reactjs, you can let me know, I will try to help if I can!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `babel standalone` script, to transcompile the code, use this script in head section:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Check the working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 
 <body>
    <div class="container" id="headContainer">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
              <img src="Panter.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
               <h1 style="color:Pink">To do, to do, to doooo</h1>
          </div>
       </div> 
    <div id="list">
       
    </div>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/babel" >
        var App = React.createClass({
           render: function(){
             return <p>Hello</p>          
           }
        })
        ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('list'))
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```